# Is there a way to receive most messages out of the standard SQS Queue? [NOT FIFO]

Tags: amazon-sqs

I tried using parallel requests but the due to retention by AWS, it does not allow to poll back the same queue unless previously polled messages are deleted.

I however achieved doing the same using the FIFO, but not the standard queue.

Thanks in Advance! 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *"it does not allow to poll back the same queue unless previously polled messages are deleted"*, I assume you're talking about the [inflight messages per queue limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html), which is pretty high at 120,000:

> For most standard queues (depending on queue traffic and message backlog), there can be a maximum of approximately 120,000 inflight messages (received from a queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue). If you reach this limit, Amazon SQS returns the OverLimit error message. To avoid reaching the limit, you should delete messages from the queue after they're processed. You can also increase the number of queues you use to process your messages. To request a limit increase, [file a support request](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sqs).

The expected use case of SQS is to have workers that receive a message, do some work, then delete the message. If you're not following this pattern, I'd strongly recommend reevaluating whether SQS is the right tool for what you're trying to do.

However, if you really have a valid use case for having more than 120K messages inflight at once, you'll need to describe your use case to AWS and get their approval to increase that limit.